# ¿Errores falsos en xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

Al compilar mi aplicación aparecen errores (10) de este estilo:

`Ambiguous use of 'get(_:estilo:)'`

Una vez eliminados los duplicados siguen apareciendo. Sin embargo, sólo existe un método get(_:estilo:) y además la aplicación compila y corre bien.

He limpiado la carpeta de compilación (Clean Build Folder) y desaparecen. Pero al cabo de 2 o 3 compilaciones vuelven a aparecer.

Otro error que aparece es:

`Ambiguous use of AZUL`

AZUL es una constante global. He eliminado la referencia a AZUL de la linea que da el error. Ahora queda así:

`self.colorBorder = NSColor.blue`

Y sigue dando el mismo error en esa linea. Incluso probé a borrar la constante AZUL pero sigue igual.

No sé si pasar de ello o qué hacer. Alguien podría ayudarme.

Saludos de Víctor.-

Comment: A qué archivo hace referencia la función `get` con click derecho?

Comment: A CeldaParrafo.swift en la función dibuja(marcoVista:) que tiene el siguiente contenido:
    
    func dibuja(marcoVista: NSRect) {
        // Variables
        let marcoVis = NSRect.marcoDocAMarcoVis(marcoVista: marcoVista, marDoc: self.marcoDoc)
        // Dibuja el fondo
        let f = NSBezierPath(rect: marcoVis)
        self.colorFondo.setFill()
        f.fill()
 
        // Obtiene el texto
        let texto = NSAttributedString.get(self.string, estilo: self.estilo)
        
        // Dibuja el texto
        texto.draw(in: marcoVis)
    }
    
    Saludos de Víctor.-

Comment: El código quedaría mejor si le agregas en la pregunta. Tengo dudas sobre esto `NSAttributedString.get`, en la documentación de [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) no veo el método `get`, estás usando alguna librería de terceros en donde tenga ese método?

Answer (score 0):

No creo que le problema se deba a la función get. Otros errores no se refieren a este método. Por ejemplo da el siguiente error: "Expected declaration" en el archivo
".../DocumentoPDF/General/Extensiones/DocPDFExt_NSAttributedString_I.swift"
Ese archivo no existe...

Comment: He reescrito la linea que da el error de get y ha desaparecido

Comment: Bueno ... pues ha vuelto a aparecer... no sé qué hacer.